# MPAndroidChart method setWordWrapEnabled() not found

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am displaying `BarChart` using mpandroidchart.
The `Legend` is displayed below the chart.
But when the number of `Labels` increases, it goes off the boundaries of the chart.
I am trying to use the below according to what is specified in the documentation,

```
Legend l = barchart.getLegend();
l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

But i am not able to find the method when i try to use it in my code.
Also, I tried to use `setMaxSizePercent()`, but this also doesn't seem to be available.
What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason therefore is that this method is **only available in the latest commit of the master branch**, but is not included in any release version yet.

I will include this in the next release as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Philipp, will this method be available for labels in xAxis as well ?  Thanks.